# Python py2exe RuntimeError

Tags: python, py2exe, 32-bit

I am on a 64-bit system using Python (32-bit), py2exe(32-bit) since I am trying to make an exe for a 32-bit system. A list of the imports in my code are: 
`import csv
import os
import time
import xlrd 
import random
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import pandas as pd
import shutil`

I followed the tutorial on the py2exe website and my setup file is the following

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['myfile.py'])
```

When I try to make my exe I get the error: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

The preceeding lines are:
File "C:\Users\S23689\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)

File "C:\Users\S23689\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 134, in import_hook
    self.msg(3, "import_hook", name, caller, fromlist, level)

These lines seem to repeat until the error message is given. Although I have Anaconda installed,  I'm  using the python file from the path C:\Python27\Scripts so I don't understand what the error message means or why it is there.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have experienced the same problem, it appears to be the pandas import. Have you overcome this issue yet?